# How to get Active status based on status field in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

> Suppose there is active and inactive state in 2 rows

```
select * from table name where status in (Active,Inactive);
```

> If active status is there need to consider that as 1st priority else need to get Inactive state

Could any one suggest some solution

```
    SCH_NAME,   STATE,  VER
```

1   pk  Planned 2
2   pk  Active 1

Comment: you need  and order by?  ...  what's do your mean with priority?

Comment: Suppose there is active and inactive state in 2 rows ,need to get Active state not inactive state

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: What did you add to your post? Should this be a sample table? Format it carefully. Didn't you see that this is not formatted well? Your sample table table has no status column but your query does.what is the output of your query? why don't you try to communicate your problem to  us? Aren't you interested in an answer? Are two rows in your sample table enough or would more rows make it more clear.

Comment: It may be useful to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by *Priority* but I think you meant to use a `CASE` condition like

```
WHERE Status = CASE 
                          WHEN Status = 'Active' 
                               THEN 'Active'
                          ELSE NULL 
                     END
```

Comment: Suppose there is active and inactive state in 2 rows ,need to get Active state not inactive state

Comment: @user3231655, provide sample data and your desired o/p

Comment: SCH_NAME,   STATE,  VER
      pk                 Planned     2
      pk                 Active         1

Answer (score 0):

I assume that (sch_name, ver) is the primary key.

Here's my solution:

1. Assign an id to every status (1: Active, 2: Planned/Passive)
2. For every row get the minimum status id for (sch_name) field and for the (sch_name, ver) fields
3. Return only the rows where the two values are equals

It works because:

- if a sch_name has an "Active" row, that will be the minimal status id (so no passive row wil be returned for that sch_name).
- if a sch_name doesn't have an "Active" row, the minimal status id will be the one assigned to "Passive", so only "Passive" rows will be returned

  ```
  create table user3231655 
  (
     schname varchar2(20),
     st   varchar2(20),
     vr   integer
   );

   delete user3231655;
   insert into user3231655 values ('pk','Active',1);
   insert into user3231655 values ('pk','Planned',2);
   insert into user3231655 values ('fk','Planned',2);

   select * from (
   select a.*, min(case st when 'Active' then 1 when 'Planned' then 2 end) ver (partition by schname) as min1,
           min(case st when 'Active' then 1 when 'Planned' then 2 end) ver (partition by schname, vr) as min2
   from user3231655 a
   ) b
   where min1=min2
  ```

There are surely more elegant ways to solve it.